# How to cast the DateTime to Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am casting `DateTime` field to Time by using `CAST` Syntax.

```
select CAST([time] as time) as [CSTTime]
```

DateTime
`2015-03-19 00:00:00.000`

Present Output : Time
`03:05:36.0000000`

I need only `HH:MM:SS` and not Milliseconds or 0000's

How to filter or Cast it to exact `HH:MM:SS` Format.

Comment: How on Earth do you get `03:05:36.0000000` from casting `2015-03-19 00:00:00.000` to a `TIME` format?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Time` is not stored with its *display format* in SQL Server.
Therefore, from the user perspective, you can say that it **has no format.**
Of course, that's not completely accurate since it does have a *storage format*, but as an average user you can't really use it.
This is true for all date and time data types:
`Date`, `DateTimeOffset`, `DateTime2`, `SmallDateTime`, `DateTime` and `Time`.

If you need a format then you don't need to cast to `time` but to a `char`. Use [`Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to get the `char` you need:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), [time], 108) as CSTTime
```

Here is some background data if you're interested:

In [this article](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/solving-datetime-mystery) published in 2000 the writer explains in depth how SQL Server treats dates and times. I doubt if anything significant changed between 2000 and 2015 in the way SQL Server stores `date`, `time` and `datetime` values internally.

Here are the relevant quotes, if you don't want to read all of it:

> **So how does SQL Server internally store the dates?** It uses 8 bytes to store a datetime value—the first 4 for the date and the second 4 for the time. SQL Server can interpret both sets of 4 bytes as integers.
>   ........
>   ........
>   SQL Server stores the second integer for the time as the number of clock ticks after midnight. A second contains 300 ticks, so a tick equals 3.3 milliseconds (ms).

since `time` is actually stored as a 4 byte integer, it really doesn't have a format as an integral part of the data type.

You might also want to check out [this article](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/162/Examine-how-DateTime2-type-stored-in-the-data-file.aspx) for a more detailed explanation with code samples.

Comment: @suslov Thanks for the formatting improvements. I'll try to live up to this standards in the future.

Comment: What is the probable solution for  HH:MM?

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun just convert to `char(5)` - like this: `convert(char(5), [timeValue], 108)`

Answer (score 21):

You can achieve it with `CAST` just simple use `TIME(0)` datatype in following:

```
SELECT CAST('2015-03-19 01:05:06.289' AS TIME(0))
```

**OUTPUT:**

`01:05:06`

Answer (score 2):

**SQL Server 2008:**

```
select cast(MyDate as time) [time] from yourtable
```

**Earlier versions:**

```
select convert(char(5), MyDate , 108) [time] from yourtable
```

**Other Options:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 114)
```

The simplest way to get the time from datetime **without millisecond** stack is:

```
SELECT CONVERT(time(0),GETDATE())
```

**Hour and Minute**

```
SELECT substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 108),0,6) AS Time
```