# Filter data from DB with datetimepicker

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql

I have two columns with date_of_delivery and date_of_receipt. I want to filter my data

```
private void button25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        if(radioButton9.Checked)
        {
            if ((Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker3.Value)) <= (Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker4.Value)))
            {
                try
                {
                    string query = "SELECT work_id, surname, first_name, patronymic, type_of_service.name_type_of_service, date_of_receipt, date_of_delivery, car_model.name_model, price_for_work FROM mechanic INNER JOIN work ON work.mechanic_id = mechanic.mechanic_id INNER JOIN type_of_service ON work.type_of_service_id = type_of_service.type_of_service_id INNER JOIN car ON work.car_id = car.car_id INNER JOIN car_model ON car.car_model_id = car_model.car_model_id WHERE work.date_of_receipt >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker3.Value) + "' AND  work.date_of_delivery <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker4.Value) + "'";
                    MessageBox.Show("" + query);
                    dataGridView2.DataSource = query;
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, SqlConn);
                    da.Fill(ds, query);
                    dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[query];
                }
                catch (Exception e2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e2.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Дата начала ремонта не может быть позже его завершения ");
            }
        }
        else if(radioButton10.Checked)
        {

            string query = "SELECT work_id, surname, first_name, patronymic, type_of_service.name_type_of_service, date_of_receipt, date_of_delivery, car_model.name_model, price_for_work FROM mechanic INNER JOIN work ON work.mechanic_id = mechanic.mechanic_id INNER JOIN type_of_service ON work.type_of_service_id = type_of_service.type_of_service_id INNER JOIN car ON work.car_id = car.car_id INNER JOIN car_model ON car.car_model_id = car_model.car_model_id WHERE work.price_for_work BETWEEN " + Convert.ToInt32(textBox16.Text) + " AND " + Convert.ToInt32(textBox17.Text) + "";
            MessageBox.Show("" + query);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = query;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, SqlConn);
            da.Fill(ds, query);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[query];
        }

    }
```

However, the data is not sorted. Because the database format of the date 01.02.2015 . How to make sure everything works

Comment: Date has no format. There is something else that's causing the problem. Try using ds.Tables[0] as the data source.

Comment: @ Zohar Peled i refresh question

Comment: Your question Title is about FILTERING, not sorting: please clarify the key issue. Best regards,

Comment: Also, always use parameterized queries or stored procedures. Your current sql is a security hazard. Google sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comments, [date types does not have a format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

You are sending a **string** that represents a date value to the database, (the default `.ToString()` of the `DateTime` object is called since there is an implicit conversion from date to string when you are concatenating the `DateTime` to the sql string).

When using strings for a date value in sql it's best to use ANSI-SQL format which is `yyyy-MM-dd`. This format guarantees that SQL Server will interpret the string as a proper date.

**However**, concatenating strings to create an SQL statement is a security hazard, since it's an opening for [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) attacks.

The proper way is to use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or stored procedures.
Replace your query's `where` clause from this

```
   WHERE work.date_of_receipt >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker3.Value) + 
"' AND  work.date_of_delivery <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker4.Value) + "'"
```

to this:

```
WHERE work.date_of_receipt >= @date_of_receipt 
AND  work.date_of_delivery <= @date_of_delivery
```

Then use the `SqlDataAdapter`'s `SelectCommand`'s `Parameters` collection to add the values for the parameters:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, SqlConn);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@date_of_receipt ", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker3.Value;
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@date_of_delivery", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker4.Value;
```

(Note that the add command returns a reference to the `SqlParameter` you've just added, therefor you can write the `.Value` to specify the value of the parameter when adding it to the `SelectCommand`.

Note that the value of the `DateTimePicker` is already a `DateTime` type, so there is no need to use `Convert.ToDateTime` when adding it.

Do the same thing with all other queries (of course, don't forget to use the proper data types for the parameters).

Answer (score -1):

System.DateTime dt16 = System.DateTime.Parse(textBox16.Text);

string sTextBox16 = dt16.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");

System.DateTime dt17 = System.DateTime.Parse(textBox17.Text);

string sTextBox17 = dt17.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");

string query = "SELECT Required Columns WHERE work.date_of_receipt >= "+sTextBox16 +"' AND  work.date_of_delivery <= '" + sTextBox17  +"'";