# 2008R2 TSQL: Convert dateadd from YYYY-MM-DD to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to convert date format from `2015-08-01` to `08/01/2015`?

I tried this:

```
DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) as 'Week Ending'
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Tip: Formatting data for display is typically done in application code, not in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function. The specific format you are looking for is `101`.

For example:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)), 101) as 'Week Ending'
```

Comment: Excellent. Be sure to upvote and/or accept answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: Seriously consider why you are formatting dates in the database. A database is generally not a 'formatting' layer. Generally you should not use it for formatting purposes.

Comment: I would also mention that [dates have no format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)...