# SQL datetime overflow. Vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem saving the system date.

In my table I have a column `date (datetime)`

But I get a "SQL datetime overflow" error in my project.

This is how I input my data

```
 Dim today As System.DateTime

 Dim cmdAddTransaction As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Scanner].[dbo].[Transaction]([ID], [Name], [Description], [Date]) VALUES(@ID, @Name, @Description, @Date)", Connection)
 cmdAddTransaction.CommandType = CommandType.Text

 cmdAddTransaction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", frm_main.txtbox_id.Text)
 cmdAddTransaction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtbox_Fname.Text)
 cmdAddTransaction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", "Edit Account")
 cmdAddTransaction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", today)

 cmdAddTransaction.ExecuteNonQuery()

 MsgBox("User Successfully Updated")
```

But as I said I get an error. Can please someone help me I want the date to be formatted like `mmm/dd/yyyy` if its possible.

Comment: why you are using varchar(max) DataType for Date column,use DateTime Datatype

Comment: Will that solve it? and is it in a mmm/dd/yyyy format? @HaveNoDisplayName

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName is still get the error

Comment: Where do you initialize the `today` variable? I don't see it in your code...

Comment: @ZoharPeled it's on the very top code sir. `Dim today as system.datetime`

Comment: That's a declaration, not an initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql server's [`Datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) data type valid range of dates is between `January 1st 1753` and `December 31th 9999`.

In your code, you don't initialize the `today` variable. That means that it's value is `January 1st 0001`. Clearly way before `January 1st 1753`.

Based on the name of the variable, I imagine it should be today's date, so you should write something like `Dim today as System.DateTime = DateTime.Today` when you declare the variable.

Comment: I declared it but when I included the `=datetime.today` it works fine now.

Comment: One last question. How can I make it a mmm/dd/yyyy format without the time?

Comment: @KristaleGenessaOrdiz-Magallo: define the column as datatype `DATE` - that's date only, no time portion. Also: **don't call your column** `date` - it's a T-SQL reserved keyword - use a **more meaningful** name, like `OrderDate`, `TransactionDate`, `VisitDate` or something - not just `date` ....

Comment: I agree with @marc_s completely. Also, you should know that [date values are not stored with display format in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028) (nor in .net, btw). you can use `Convert` or `Format` (depending on your sql server version) on the select statement, or simply format the values in the presentation layer (better practice.)