# Change date format in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, datepicker

I have a table which stores dates of an event.I display the dates in a few labels.Everything works fine.BUT i want to display my dates in the format 'dd-mm-yyyy' and the date is stored in sql server as 'mm/dd/yyyy'.

```
 Create table testDate
 (
 EventStart date
 EventEnd date
 )
```

The dates come from datepicker and i dont want to format my dates in datepicker because it gives me conversion problems. I want to change the format when i display the date in asp.net Label.
Right now i dsiplay the date as below :

```
 string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsActiveConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from testdate", con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            DateTime Received;
            DateTime.TryParse(rdr["EventStart"].ToString(),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out Received);
            Label1.Text = Received.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Sql server does not store date display format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to parse it anyway. SQL Server saves DateTime in a binary format. It doesn't have *any* format. Format concept only an issue when you get their *textual* representation.

Just cast it to `DateTime` (which is [`date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) mapped with `DateTime` in CLR side) and use [custom date and time format specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get it's string representation with which format you want.

```
Label1.Text = ((DateTime)rdr["EventStart"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

By the way, I *strongly* suspect you need to use month instead of minutes. That's why you need to change your `mm` part to `MM`. `mm` specifier is for minutes and `MM` specifier is for months.

Use `using` statement to dispose your `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` objects like you did your connection.

Do not use `select *` by the way. [It is kind of bad practice](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-08/its-not-about-the-star-stupid).

Comment: Thank you.This just solved the big datetime mystery for me.