# C# and SQL server datetime format

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have the following C# method to update a value in a SQL server:

```
public void Save()
{
    int TotalFail = TotalRecords - SuccessCount;

    DataAccess_MSSQLServer oDAM = new DataAccess_MSSQLServer();

    try
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        oDAM.Update("Update TBL_FulfilmentBatch SET ReturnDate = " + oDAM.GetFieldValueSQL(processDate) + ", TotalSuccess = " + oDAM.GetFieldValueSQL(SuccessCount) + ", TotalFail = " + oDAM.GetFieldValueSQL(TotalFail) + ", ProcessedDate = " + oDAM.GetFieldValueSQL(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")) + " WHERE FulfilmentHouseID = (SELECT FulfilmentHouseID FROM TBL_fulfilmentHouse WHERE [Description] Like 'Current') AND BatchNumber = " + oDAM.GetFieldValueSQL(batchNumber));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace);
    }

}
```

Where

```
oDAM.GetFieldValueSQL
```

is a method used to format strings etc for SQL statements.

The string `processDate` has the value: `2015-07-23`

The field this corresponds to in the database is a datetime field.

I also have:

```
ProcessedDate = " + oDAM.GetFieldValueSQL(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))
```

which inserts a C# datetime field in the database.

These 2 datetime fields should now be in the same date format.

The problem is that when inserted into the databse, they come out as follows:

[image]

Which is opposite formats.

why is this happening?

They are both being passed in as strings, in the same format.

There is nothing in the table that tells it to convert to a particular datetime format.

Older entries of the ProcessedDate column are in American format.

Does it think this date is in American format aswell?

What can I do?

Comment: 1. [Sql server does not store date display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028) 2. Always use parameterized queries. read about sql injection.

Comment: Use a parametrized insert and pass a DateTime type or why not use `GETDATE()` in the SQL for the servers current time? As the values are not quoted yyyy-mm-dd is a *subtraction* operation ...

Comment: Pass yyyyMMddHHmmssFFF instead of yyyyMMddHHmmss e.g.
ProcessedDate = " + oDAM.GetFieldValueSQL(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssFFF")). Would that help You?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use parameterized queries.

If you keep trying, eventually you'll manage to tweak your `string` into format that "works". For *your current* database instance, running the client application on *your* computer. It might break on the 13th of the month (when days are mistaken for months).

The ADO.NET providers can translate a `DateTime` and other primitive types for you, and prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities at the same time. You will probably even see a performance gain if you reuse the `DbCommand`s.