# Date format issue SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, firebird

I have a source third party system that uses a Firebird database. You can setup a Windows service of this third party system to write data into a sql server database. Recently I get these exceptions:

> 00:00:40 CallProcessor.exe##Error##22##[The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value@006D5C65] @ :TMSSQLAccess.ExecuteQuery - exception running query : ##Threadid:12576##

The reason must be that my database language is not correct - I think. This is my current setting:

```
select @@language
British
```

Looking at Firebird's text data, I can see entries like this (I have written a C# client to parse firebird's raw data):

```
31/08/2011 16:58:00
```

This looks correct to me (British format). However, if I do:

```
select getdate()
```

I get:

```
2016-02-18 08:18:27.477
```

So I am a bit confused about what to do. Please note that I cannot touch the server (i.e. change its language/time zone/date format). However, I have full control of the SQL Server.

PS:

I just traced an insert statement it looks like this:

```
insert into calls (  site, calldateandtime, initial, calltype, callfrom, callto, ring, talk, phone, account, costcurrency, costregion, reason, special, extras, provoiceid, callid, agentid, talkgroup, cost, sourcedate)values ( 1, '02/18/16 09:11:24', 'Y', 2, '102', '4387', 9, 81, '07841269657', '{8D65BD48-5114-4', '£', 4, 0, 1234, '', '', '{522DBFD9-52D9-437A-B254-9498A92A854D}', '{8D65B', '', 0.00, '02/18/16 00:00:00')
go
SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON
go
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS newID

go
```

Comment: Use `103` style to insert. `select convert(date,'31/08/2011 16:58:00',103)`

Comment: I am not in control of the inserting - this is the problem. I need to make the target (my sql server db over which I have full control) ready to cope with the format pumped into it. I believe it arrives in this format: 31/08/2011 16:58:00.

Comment: How are the dates stored in the Firebird server, because it looks like they are string values, and not `TIMESTAMP`. Or did you do a conversion yourself between getting the value from Firebird and sending it to SQL Server?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - not sure all I see are the traced insert statements which allowed me to adapt the database settings to us/english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your insert statement the date is `'02/18/16 09:11:24'` - note that the string is formatted as `MM/dd/yyyy`, and not `dd/MM/yyyy` as you suspected.
Therefore you need to change the date format of the server to `MDY`.
This can be done by setting either the language to `us_english` (that implicitly changes the date format to `MDY`), or the setting the date format directly to `MDY`.

If you can control the insert statement then use the `101` style for american date format:

```
convert(datetime, @datestring, 101) -- will work for @datestring = '02/18/16 09:11:24'
```

BTW, [dates in sql server are not stored with the display format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028) that's why you get the sql-ansi standard format when you execute `select getdate()`

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a stored proc to insert into calls table? You could accept date as string (varchar) and then convert into desired datetime format inside the stored proc like this:

```
SELECT @calldateandtime = convert(smalldatetime, @calldateandtime, 103)
```