# How to convert date in mm/dd/yyyy format to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, format

I'm inserting data into a table and before inserting I need to check if data exists.

I have a composite key consisted of two columns of `datetime` and `int`.

Before inserting I need to check if the data with the same time and id exists in the table.

The date that user is inserting is in 'mm/dd/yyyy'.

The `datetime` data in the table looks like this: '2016-01-12 00:00:00.000'.
The id field is `int`.

So, I have a query:

```
if not exists(select count(*) from table_1 where MyDate = @myDate and id = @id)
insert into table_1 .....
```

What is the right way to format the date user sends to match the `datetime` format in the table?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning that [Sql server does not store date display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

Answer (score 0):

Check this sqlfiddle about how to use different date formats in your query. Might help you to solve it.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd0b7/5

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the question is about SQL Server, based on the syntax.  The issues in the code snippet far transcend date formats.

First, the expression:

```
if not exists(select count(*) from table_1 where MyDate = @myDate and id = @id)
```

will never return true, because the subquery *always* returns one row with one column.  If nothing matches, the column contains `0`, which does exist.

You intend:

```
if not exists(select 1 from table_1 where MyDate = @myDate and id = @id)
```

Second, this check is not necessary if you wisely choose to have the *database* enforce the uniqueness constraint.  So, define a unique index or constraint on the two columns:

```
create unique index unq_table_1_id_mydate on table_1(id, MyDate);
```

Now, the database won't let you insert duplicate values and no `if` is necessary.

Next, I would suggest that you fix the date format at the application layer.  YYYY-MM-DD is an ISO standard date format and quite reasonable.  However, if you don't want to do that, use `convert()`:

```
insert into table_1(id, MyDate, .....)
    select @id, convert(datetime, @MyDate, 101), . . .
```

The value in the database looks to be correct stored as a date/time value, so this should work fine.

Comment: That n you for your answer, but I need to use the table which is given to me and defined without a unique index

Answer (score 0):

You can use following line to convert date to required format in SQL server:

```
select FORMAT(@your_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'en-US') from Your_Table
```