# Why SQL Server CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returning the date/time in 12 hour format

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, amazon-rds

I expect the current time in 24 hour format when I use the following query.

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

However, it returns this. (Note that the current time is 6.41PM)

```
2016-02-24 06:41:10.260
```

This is a Amazon RDS Sql Server instance.

However, my local server gives the following result, which is I am expecting.

```
2016-02-24 17:42:41.387
```

How can I configure the database so that it gives me the time in 24 hour format?

Comment: Are you sure your "local" server is in the same timezone as your RDS instance?

Comment: SELECT 
CASE WHEN Product.LaunchTime < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Active
FROM Product where Product.ProductID=12345

returns 0

Thus it seems to be nothing to do with the client. Please note that the launch time is 11AM and current time is 6PM

Comment: [Sql server does not store date display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon RDS SQL Server database time is fixed to UTC. Even if you are in a different geographical region you cannot change the database time.

Thus, any queries that uses CURRENT_TIMESTAMP needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Date format can also be set by using below query:

```
alter SESSION set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'date_format';
```

e.g.: `alter SESSION set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';`