# Format date as 'DD Month YYYY'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Just have a mssql query that has a date in the format:

```
'2016-03-22 00:00:00.000'
```

I need to format it as:

```
'22 March 2016'
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I've tried googling and the usual 106, 112 codes don't seem to work.

Is there a specific code format I can use?

Comment: I've also looked at using DATEPART but it seems unnecessarily long way of doing it. Just wondering if there is a easier way..

Comment: Using `DATEPART`: `SELECT 
 RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ' ' +
 DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) + ' ' +
 CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())  AS VARCHAR(4))`

Comment: @Aug Check my answer it may helpful to you.

Comment: There is no need write so long query so far just need `convert your date into datetime` and apply sql date format whatever format want to apply on it.

Comment: [date time values have no display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [**`FORMAT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'D', 'en-gb')
```

If your version does not support the `FORMAT` function, you can do it by concatenating the date parts:

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ' ' +
    DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) + ' ' +
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())  AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Comment: i Upvoted this answer. But in reality your comment using DATEPART worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use Format Function in SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dd-MMMM-yyyy')
```

See Image for your datatype ref
[image]

Comment: getdate gets the current date.. i tried replacing that with tourdate_end which is the fields name and it didnt work.. FORMAT(tourdate_end, 'dd-MMMM-yy')

Comment: What is the datatype of tourdate_end?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-03-22 00:00:00.000'), 106)
```

You need to convert into `DATETIME` then you will get your desired output

[More Datetime Sql formate](https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eef4ff/5)

This may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try Convert function for SQL server:

```
select convert(varchar(11),cast('2016-03-22 00:00:00.000' as datetime), 106)
```

Answer (score 0):

How to change day, month, year in PHP:

```
echo $purchase_date=date('F-Y',strtotime('2022-03-22 00:00:00.000'));
```

Answer:

```
March-2022
```

Comment: But the question is for SQL, not PHP

Comment: This question is specifically tagged as a SQL question. Please avoid adding answers in other languages, as they add noise to the answers, and can cause confusion for others who have the same question later on.