# How to convert a varchar field type containing date to a proper date format

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I have a varchar field that contains date values like:

```
02042015
```

How do I convert it to DATE format that should return the value something like:

```
2 Apr 2015
```

Comment: What have you tried? The first thing you need to do is confirm that every record in your database follows this format.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes all the records in the database do contain the same format...

Comment: [Date have no display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028) If you need a display format, you want to convert a string to another string.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Actuallt I haven't tried anything... I am very new to database just starting off learning DB these days.... Trying out the script mentioned in the below answer by Yousuf

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought there would be some conversion format so you could put:

```
select(convert(datetime,'010109',<some magic number>))
```

and get the result, but I can't seem to find one that gives the right date

You can try this as well:

```
declare @dt varchar(6)
select @dt = '010109'
select convert(datetime,RIGHT(@dt,2) + SUBSTRING(@dt,3,2) + LEFT(@dt,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**CONVERT**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with `106` format in following:

```
declare @date varchar(60) = '02042015'
select convert(varchar(20),cast(right(@date,4) + substring(@date,3,2) + left(@date,2) as datetime), 106)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
02 Apr 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @V_DATE VARCHAR(20) = '02042015'
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(11), 
            CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(@V_DATE,4)+LEFT(@V_DATE,2)+SUBSTRING(@V_DATE,3,2))
            ,106)
```