# Convert from VARCHAR to DATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to convert all values in a table and I need that change to be permanent so the table has dates and they are formatted like `dd.mm.yyy`.

I need to change them to `DATETIME` Format which is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: CAST(FieldName as datetime) You really need to give more information, some sample data and what you've already tried and what has and hasn't worked

Comment: The stored format is "dd.mm.yyy" or "dd.mm.yyyy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dates are stored with the appropriate data type (date, datetime or datetime2), then they are [stored without any display format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

If that is the case you need to convert them to `char(10)` when selecting the data:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), DateTimeColumn, 120)
```

If they are stored as a string type, you should refactor your database and store them properly. If that's impossible for some reason, you can convert twice. one from string to date, and the other one back to string:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), CONVERT(date, DateTimeStringColumn, 104), 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CONVERT` function with style `20`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,yourdatefield,20)
```

Outputs:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,yourData,104),20)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format is "dd.mm.yyyy".
 Follow the steps.

1. Add New Column

   ```
       ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN_NAME DATETIME/DATE;
   ```
2. Update the column with date value from old column

   ```
       UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME=CONVERT(DATETIME,V_DATE_COL,104);
   ```
3. Remove Old Column

   ```
       ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP COLUMN V_DATE_COL
   ```
4. Rename New Column

   ```
       EXEC sp_RENAME 'TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME' , 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'
   ```