# convert datetime in 24 hour format in derived column ssis

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis

I have several datetime field which I need the time to be in 24 hour format.

Interval Start Time
2016-01-04 03.30

I need its as

Interval Start Time
2016-01-04 15.30

I developed this code in Derived Column in SSIS. But I don't think this is correct:

```
(DATEPART("Hh",[Interval Start Time]) == 01 ? "13" : 
    (DATEPART("Hh",[Interval Start Time]) == 02 ? "14" :
        (DATEPART("Hh",[Interval Start Time]) == 03 ? "15" :
            (DATEPART("Hh",[Interval Start Time]) == 04 ? "16" : 
            (DATEPART("Hh",[Interval Start Time]) == 05 ? "17" : 
                "")))))
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you differentiate between actual 3AM and 3PM?

Comment: The service runs between 9am to 5.30pm so there won't be any service at 3am so 03.30 will be 15.30. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(16), [Interval Start Time], 120)
```

If you want to have the time delimiter a dot (`.`) instead of a colon (`:`), you can add `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(char(16), [Interval Start Time], 120), ':', '.')
```

btw, [`Datetime` data type doesn't store display format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

Comment: @ Zohar the answer you provided:  SELECT CONVERT(char(16), [Interval Start Time], 120) doesn't work. I still get the time 01:30 when I should get 13.30.

Comment: Are you sure? [check this online demo.](http://rextester.com/VKLN35066)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to add 12 hours to each datetime, E.g.

```
DATEADD(HOUR, 12, [Interval Start Time])
```

Or, to replicate the logic in your question you could apply the addition conditionally:

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, [Interval Start Time]) <= 5 THEN [Interval Start Time] ELSE DATEADD(HOUR, 12, [Interval Start Time]) END
```

Comment: @Chris This doesn't work either. I still get 01:30 when I should be getting 13.30. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert the datetime to 24h format then you can try the below query.

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),getdate(),121);
Or
select CONVERT(datetime,getdate(),121);

OUTPUT : 2016-07-28 20:14:10.937
```

Comment: 1. better use `char` for a fixed length string instead of `varchar`. 2. the time resolution in the question is minutes, no point of showing a time resolution of milliseconds. 3. your second statement converts a `datetime` to `datetime`. I'm guessing you meant to convert it to `varchar`...

Comment: I wanted to do this in derived column in SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR([Interval Start Time])+"-"+
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2) MONTH([Interval Start Time]),2)+ "-"+ 
RIGHT( "0" + (DT_WSTR,2) DAY([Interval Start Time]),2) +" "+
(datepart("hour",[Interval Start Time]) == 1 ? "13" : 
datepart("hour",[Interval Start Time]) == 2 ? "14" :
datepart("hour",[Interval Start Time]) == 3 ? "15" : 
datepart("hour",[Interval Start Time]) == 4 ? "16" :  
datepart("hour",[Interval Start Time]) == 5 ? "17" : "" )
+"."+RIGHT( "0" + (DT_WSTR,2) datepart("mi",[Interval Start Time]),2)
```

thinking you were looking for the expression for the SSIS task 'Derived Column' and supposing that 'Interval Start Time' is datetime.
I hope this help.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get an error. "Error at the Data Flow Task: The function "Year" does not support the data type "DT_WSTR".

Comment: it is a simple cast , it always works..Are you using Expression in Derived Column?

Comment: The 'Interval Start Time' is already a datetime format which I used: (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)[Interval Start Time] in the derived column.

Comment: What I have done is to rewrite [Interval Start Time] starting from the year etc ... you must enter the cast to DT_WSTR because there are characters in the variable as a '+', 
in this way it recreates the date with the desired format...so no need to use the cast  (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)[Interval Start Time] in Expression builder.