# change date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a date field called TimeStampUTC in `2016-08-01 03:00:00.000` format but I need to return it in `01/08/2016`

I'm using the following query

```
SELECT   Convert(varchar(2),DATEPART(DAY, a.TimeStampUTC)) + '/'+ Convert(varchar(2),DATEPART(MONTH, a.TimeStampUTC)) + '/' + Convert(varchar(4),DATEPART(year, a.TimeStampUTC))   AS Date FROM table AS a   WHERE a.TimeStampUTC > '$startDate' AND a.TimeStampUTC <='$endDate'
```

Issue is it return as `1/8/2016`

How to write the query to return it as `01/08/2016` way.

Comment: how about `convert(varchar(15),TimeStampUTC,101)`

Comment: @SankarRaj Are you suggest to use this without convert day,month and year separately ?

Comment: If it's a date field, no need to parse out the components, you can convert to a string with one of many formats.

Comment: Exactly. Why you want to do it separately?

Comment: Simply use this: CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE
(),103)

Comment: Here's a handy list of date format numbers: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Comment: [Sql server does not store date display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get different datetime formats by using `CONVERT()` function,

```
SELECT   
Convert(varchar(15),TimeStampUTC,103 )   AS Date 
FROM table AS a   
WHERE a.TimeStampUTC > '$startDate' AND a.TimeStampUTC <='$endDate'
```

Here you can find the different date format codes: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use **DATE_FORMAT()**

> DATE_FORMAT(*yourdate*,'%d-%m-%Y')

for your reference: [sql date formats](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Comment: SQL Server has no `DATE_FORMAT()` function, SQL Server 2012 and newer have `FORMAT()`, but the way you input the date format is different than what you have here.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @TimeStampUTC datetime='2016-08-01 03:00:00.000' 
        select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),convert(date,@TimeStampUTC),103)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for DD/MM/YYYY, you can try this:

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(15), a.TimeStampUTC, 105),'-','/')
```

Comment: No need to replace dashes with slashes, can just use format code `103`. Also 103 and 105 both have day first, not month.

Comment: Yes, that works too ! Thank you Hart, i learnt something new as well :)