# Converting Date Format SQL to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have the date format `2016-11-23 16:47:21.007` and I am trying to convert it with this SQL:

`update user_table set login_date = CONVERT(datetime,login_date,120)`

So that I only get `2016-11-23 16:47:21` but it's currently just staying as the same format.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is the expected output format?

Comment: Is login_date a datetime or a varchar?

Comment: It seems your `login_date` column is already a `datetime`, so there is no need to reformat it since it has no intrinsic format.  You just need formatting when you are going to output it not when storing it.

Comment: I want this format `2016-11-23 16:47:21.007` to be converted to this format `2016-11-23 16:47:21` Just basically without the milliseconds

Comment: @wdosanjos ... and it doesn't make much sense to update a datetime column with a varchar.  I'm surprised it even runs without error, let alone that it doesn't change the column.

Comment: login_date is datetime, I wanted to converted just the general format/layout of the datetime

Comment: if it's just for displaying you can use `select CONVERT(varchar(19),'2016-11-23 16:47:21.007',120)` but as everyone suggests, converting it is pretty silly since you need to convert it back to use it as a datetime. I suggest you handle this on the application side.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen MSSQL will implicitly parse the `varchar` value to a `datetime`. That's why it doesn't fail.

Comment: @wdosanjos So the whole operation ends up basically being a no-op.  Thanks, I just learned something new.

Answer (score 5):

Your current requirement is mainly a *presentation* need.  Since your `login_date` is already stored as a `datetime`, there is no need to change anything internally in your database.

When you need to *present* the `login_date` without milliseconds, then go ahead and call `CONVERT` as you were:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(19), login_date, 120) AS login_date_no_millis
FROM yourTable
```

But there is no need to do the `UPDATE` you showed us in your question.

Comment: don't you need a varchar not a datetime for the conversion?

Comment: You should specify a length for your `varchar` - [not only because it is a good idea to always do so in general](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx), but also because in this case you can use the length to omit the milliseconds, which is what the OP asking for. No real impact here but you can probably also use `char` because the output will always be the same length.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that [Sql server does not store date display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

Answer (score 0):

Altering the column to datatype datetime2(0) will mean milliseconds aren't stored. If you're certain you don't need them.

Equally, casting it to datetime2(0) in your select will do the same in the presentation level whilst maintaining the milliseconds in the database if required. Also means that unlike cast/convert to varchar, it's still a datetime value rather than a string if that makes a difference to the app.