# Convert date from 1/26/2016 14:54 format to 20160126 in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

Having date in `1/26/2016 14:54` format and need it in `20160126` format in MSSQL.
I am using `REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, DATE_OF_AQUISITION,112),'-','')`

but it is giving error

> "Msg 9807, Level 16, State 0, Line 47 The input character string does
>   not follow style 112, either change the input character string or use
>   a different style."

Comment: [Date is stored without display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30033028/3094533)

Comment: @mohit if it's helps you need to up vote the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Example But I'm not sure

Just remove **112** conversion you have added

```
declare @dt VARCHAR(20) = '1/26/2016 14:54'

select REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE,@dt),'-','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to date before replace.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE,DATE_OF_AQUISITION), 112),'/','')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is example which show a result that you want.

Hope this is also help for you.

select Convert(varchar,TaskDate,112) TaskDate from XYZ.

Result-20161121