# SQL Datetime format change

Tags: sql-server

I am having below formatted Date time value in my SQL Server database table.

```
2017-02-01 14:31:53.000
2017-09-01 14:54:11.000
```

I want to swap the Month & Date values like

```
2017-01-02 14:31:53.000 
2017-01-09 14:54:11.000
```

Is there any way to achieve it?
There are multiple records with such format.

I tried using Excel to convert the same and create query. but it is not working.

Comment: It would be better to let sql server handle the storing part. You need to convert the datetime coming from db to whatever format you want.

Comment: Actually there was some error while entering data in SQL before by previous application. It swapped the places of month & date. Now I am going to correct it... The dates you are seeing are 2 & 9 of January 2017.

Comment: DateTime are stored without it's display format. If you are storing DateTime values in a varchar column you should change it to a DateTime column.

Comment: Column's data type is date time only.

Comment: But it did not threw error due to Months value was not greater than 12.

Comment: Ok. You can wrire code to retrieve such records, convert datetime to string, swap month and date by string operation, convert it back to datetime using proper format string and update it to db using parameterized queries.

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: Solved it by writing application to convert date time in desired format....

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in my comment, [DateTime are stored without display format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028).
If you want to select the dates in a specific format, you need to use either [`Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) (available in versions 2012 or higher) or [`CONVERT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) (supports only predefined formats)

Now, assuming your desired format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss`, you can use convert with 120 style:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(19), DateTimeColumn, 120) As FormattedDateTime
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
@formatString(varchar)
- the format string to use (Examples "dd mm yyyy", "mmm.dd.yy")
Description:

Formats a given date based on the format specified in @formatString
d - one digit day (when applicable)
dd- two digit day
ddd- short day name
dddd- long day name
m- one digit month (when applicable)
mm- two digit month
mmm- short month name
mmmm- long month name
yy- two digit year
yyyy- four digit year
*/
create function dbo.fnFormatDate
(
 @inputDate datetime,
 @formatString varchar(25)
)
returns varchar(20) as
begin
declare @returnValue varchar(25)

-- Declare local vairables
declare @formattedDate varchar(25),
@day varchar(20), @month varchar(20), @year varchar(20),
@dayFormat varchar(5), @monthFormat varchar(5), @yearFormat varchar(5)

set @dayFormat = ''
set @monthFormat = ''
set @yearFormat = ''

-- Convert the supplied date to day mon year (25 Jan 2008)
set @formattedDate = convert(varchar, @inputDate, 106)

-- If the format string contains a format for the day
if charindex('d', @formatString) > 0
 -- Get the day format string
 set @dayFormat = master.dbo.fn_pcre_replace(@formatString, '.*?(d{1,4}).*',     '$1')

-- If the format string contains a format for the month
if charindex('m', @formatString) > 0
-- Get the month format string
set @monthFormat = master.dbo.fn_pcre_replace(@formatString, '.*?    (m{1,4}|M{1,4}).*', '$1')
```

-- If the format string contains a format for the year
   if charindex('y', @formatString) > 0
   -- Get the year format string
   set @yearFormat = master.dbo.fn_pcre_replace(@formatString, '.*?(y{2,4}).*',     '$1')

-- Format the day value based on the format string for the day
   select@day =
   case @dayFormat
   when 'dd' then master.dbo.fn_pcre_replace(@formattedDate, '^(\d+).*', '$1')
   when 'ddd' then substring(datename(dw, @formattedDate), 1, 3)
   when 'dddd' then datename(dw, @formattedDate)
   else convert(varchar, day(@formattedDate))
   end

-- Format the month value based on the format string for the month
   select@month =
   case @monthFormat
    when 'mm' then master.dbo.fn_pcre_replace(convert(varchar, @inputDate, 101),   '^(\d+)/.*', '$1')
    when 'mmm' then master.dbo.fn_pcre_replace(@formattedDate, '\d+\s(\w+)\s\d+', '$1')
   when 'mmmm' then datename(m, @formattedDate)
   else convert(varchar, month(@formattedDate))
   end

-- Format the year value based on the format string for the year
   select@year =
   case @yearFormat
   when 'yy' then substring(convert(varchar, year(@formattedDate)), 3, 2)
   else convert(varchar, year(@formattedDate))
   end

set @returnValue = @formatString

-- If the day format was specified
   if @dayFormat <> ''
   -- Replace the day format string with the actual day value
   set @returnValue = master.dbo.fn_pcre_replace(@returnValue, @dayFormat, @day)

-- If the month format was specified
   if @monthFormat <> ''
   -- Replace the month format string with the actual month
   set @returnValue = master.dbo.fn_pcre_replace(@returnValue, @monthFormat, @month)

-- If the year format was specified
   if @yearFormat <> ''
   -- Replace the year format string with the actual year
   set @returnValue = master.dbo.fn_pcre_replace(@returnValue, @yearFormat,  @year)

-- Return the formated value
   return @returnValue
end

Comment: Vijay, hope this might help.

Comment: While creating function it gives me error at this line:    master.dbo.fn_pcre_replace