# How to convert every column in a table to date time? Mon d yyyy hH:mmAM

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I'm trying to update every column in a table to Datetime (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm`) from `mon dd yyyy hh:mmAM`. I've wrote a script that affects columns however no column seem to get updated.

```
UPDATE ParadataDetail
SET Value = Convert(datetime, Value, 120)
WHERE MetaDataId = 29
```

Comment: Why you want to update date in DB?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Not every software product that has "SQL" on its name is the same thing.

Comment: Judging by the code I've removed the irrelevant MySql Tag. What is the datatype of the `Value` column?

Comment: what is value and datetime in query?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some product specific SQL there...)

Comment: [Sql server does not store date display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028), so if the data type of the `Value` column is `DateTime` then your query is meaningless.

Comment: Value is Varchar(2048). I'm using SQL Server. It needs to be stored as a VarChar in datetime format.

Comment: I understand I'm trying to put a datetime into a varchar, the script is obviously wrong

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). Don't keep date values in a varchar column. Change the data type to DateTime.

Comment: It's an old out dated DB, it's not mine, it's my works. Value isn't always a datetime format. It can have ints. emails etc in, needs to be VarChar(2048). We have a MetaDataId to tell us what value is. 29 is datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your best option would be to change the data type of the `Value` column to DateTime.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) If that's impossible for some reason, and you really, and I do mean really must keep datetime values in a varchar column, and you need to change the string representation of the datetime value, you can use a double conversion:

```
UPDATE  ParadataDetail
SET Value = Convert(varchar(2048), Convert(datetime, Value, 100), 120)
WHERE MetaDataId = 29
```

If your sql server version is 2012 or higher, you better use Try_convert:

```
UPDATE  ParadataDetail
SET Value = Convert(varchar(2048), Try_Convert(datetime, Value, 100), 120)
WHERE MetaDataId = 29
```

This will set all the values that can't be converted to datetime as null.

Comment: I know it a terrible thing to do, it's a generic system for work.This has worked perfectly though, thank you.