# convert date time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

In SQL server, date is getting saved in the following format:-

```
2017-02-20 05:59:58.537
```

But I need the output in the following format:

```
20/Feb/2017 11:29:58 AM
```

Comment: Refer: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Why are you storing dates as `VARCHAR`?

Comment: SQL stores  the date as per the default setting. while fetching that date you need to convert that date according to your requirement. You can try this   http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct Answer:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), getdate(), 113), ' ', '/') + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(TIME, getdate()), 22)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
select  replace(convert(varchar(11),GETDATE(),113), ' ', '/')+ ' '+    RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 22), 11);
```

Comment: @Asad: If an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: @zohar query is not working fine after 12 hours after 12 it should come as 01:10:15 PM but now its showing as 13:10:15 PM .. can we add AM and PM in 24 hours format ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT replace(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106), ' ', '/')+' '+right(getdate(),7)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , but its not getting the output as per its given in question. Missing is 'seconds'

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below conversion method :

 DECLARE @DATE DATETIME = '2017-02-20 05:59:58.537'
 SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),@DATE,113), ' ', '/') + ' ' 
 +CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@DATE,108)+' ' +RIGHT(@DATE,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL stores the date as per the default setting (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:ms). while fetching that date you need to convert that date according to your requirement.

[Try this](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx)

Comment: Wrong. [Sql server stores dates as numbers.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

Answer (score 0):

I have a date Function I use, and you could modify it to include details for hours, minutes and seconds, too.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_DateDisplay]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @dateIn date
)
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @dateOut nvarchar(MAX)

    DECLARE @yearIn int
    DECLARE @monthIn int
    DECLARE @dayIn int

    DECLARE @monthOut nvarchar(3)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SET @yearIn = YEAR ( @dateIn ) 
    SET @monthIn = MONTH ( @dateIn ) 
    SET @dayIn = DAY ( @dateIn ) 

    SET @monthOut = SUBSTRING ( DATENAME ( MONTH , @dateIn ) , 1 , 3 )

    SET @dateOut = CONCAT ( @dayIn , ' ' , @monthOut , ' ' , @yearIn )

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @dateOut

END
```