# Convert datetime formats to a particular format in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, msbi

Destination column data should in one format:

[image]

How to do the HireDate column in one format at destination table of sql server.

Comment: Your source formats are ambiguous. Is `01/10/2008` 1st Oct or 10th Jan? You don't know so you can't convert it. Also *forget* about date 'formats' in SQL Server. Choose the correct datatype `DATE` and forget about visual format

Comment: Unless you have some way to determin the date format used in each record in the flat file, it can't be done correctly. As @Nick.McDermaid wrote - all dates where the day is less then 13 will be ambiguous. Also, you should know that [datetime data type does not save display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

Comment: If it have only two types of formats i.e. yyyy/mm/dd or dd/mm/yyyy than can we change to yyyy/mm/dd format? @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: But how do you know which row has which format? How do you know Sumit is `dd/mm/yyyy` and not `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: Once you have established that you need to try something yourself and post your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Add a script component , Mark `HireDate` as input column, add a new Output column `outHireDate` with dataType `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`

In the script write the following:

Declare an array of formats:

```
Dim strFormats() as string = {"dd/MM/yyyy","yyyy/MM/dd","MM/dd/yyyy"}
```

And in  `Input0_ProcessInputRow` sub use  `DateTime.ParseExact` Function as follow:

```
Row.OutHireDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.HireDate,strFormats,New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

**Important note**

It may cause conflict when day and month are lower than `13` (ex: 01/03/2010)

Comment: This is pointless if we don't know which row has which format.

Comment: @NickMcDermaid I agree with that, this is what i mean in the important note in my answer

Comment: What about validating in an "if" statements first or do a try parse (nested if needed).