# Convert DateTime format to Another DateTime Format In C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

In my C# project I need system date time to another specific date time format.

My system datetime format is like `"15/03/2017 9:25 AM"` --->that can be changed according to computer wich my program run.

But I need to parse that datetime format to another date time format something like "2017-03-15 9:25 AM"----> save date in SQL datebase accept this format only.

I need Assign this to variable to  Datetime Variable not need save in String variable.

I tried this code but not working

```
string datetimesss = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

It returns

```
// value of datetimesss="2017-03-15 09:33:25"
```

Then i parse again to date time format

```
 DateTime dates = DateTime.Parse(datetimesss);
```

It returns

```
// value of dates ="15/03/2017 9:42:43 AM"
```

Convert back to my computer datetime format .How can I convert any datetime format to  DateTime `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`

Thank You!

Comment: This might help on your question. [DateTime Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: What is your actual requirement? what is the type of input that you are dealing with?

Comment: what is the **expectedInput** and **expectedOutput**, this is a bit unclear

Comment: [Sql server does not store date display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028). Nor does c#. Further more, c# DateTime struct maps directly to Sql Server DateTime data type, so there really is no need to bother with string representation formats. Just pass dates as parameters and you'll be fine.

Comment: @un-lucky 'DateTime.Now' gave current system time.but that can be change according to computer user requirement. how i Assign current system date time to DateTime variable format Like ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I got the point,
I parse DateTime to String

```
string sqlupdatepassword = "UPDATE  [User] SET  Last_loign_date ='" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt") + "'";
```

In SQl database "Last_loign_date" is datetime format.
this may not correct, but this worked for me.

thanks!

Comment: You got the *wrong* point. It's only when you're treating the dates as strings that they even *have* a format. If you just keep your data in `DateTime` variables, and *avoid* strings, there's no conversions to perform. When you interact with SQL Server, you can keep your data as `DateTime` data by using *parameters* - which is also a good habit to get into using anyway since it's the safest way to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If I upadate like this its not working.return exception                                                                                      "ERROR [22007] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

ERROR [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated."

Comment: But that's because, somewhere along the line, you've again converted your `DateTime` value into a *string*. If you can *avoid* the string conversions, you can *avoid* formatting issues.

Answer (score 2):

You should *avoid* strings and just keep your data in `DateTime` variables. ADO.Net already knows how to translate between .NETs `DateTime` and SQL Server's `datetime` - and neither of these *has* a format (both of them, internally, are just numbers. .NETs `DateTime` is a count of 100ns intervals since 01/01/0001. SQL Server's datetime is a count of whole and fractional days since 01/01/1900).

Something like:

```
var updateCommand = new SqlCommand(
         "UPDATE  [User] SET  Last_loign_date =@LastLoginDate"
         ,conn); //Assume conn is an SqlConnection object
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastLoginDate",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
```

or, in the alternative, why not use the *database* server time rather than passing it:

```
string sqlupdatepassword = "UPDATE  [User] SET  Last_loign_date =current_timestamp";
```

Answer (score 1):

If sql server language is set as us-english then your date - > '15/03/2017 9:25 AM' will be considered as text and converting into date will not give correct results. You need create date based on day,month and year from your given date by using string functions. Use the below code to get required output :

```
declare @date varchar(30) = '15/03/2017 9:25 AM'

select  cast(left(parsename(replace(@date,'/','.'),1),4) + 
        parsename(replace(@date,'/','.'),2) + 
        parsename(replace(@date,'/','.'),3) as datetime) +
        ltrim(stuff(parsename(replace(@date,'/','.'),1),1,4,''))
```