# Format Time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

How can I format time to only display Hours and minutes?
For example Id like `LessonTime TIME(0),` to show 12:00 rather than 12:00:00.

```
USE [Assignment]
GO
PRINT 'Creating database tables...'
CREATE TABLE [PupilDetails](
Pupil_ID INT  NOT NULL, 
FName VARCHAR(20),
LName VARCHAR(20),
DOB DATE,
LessonDay VARCHAR (10),
LessonTime TIME(0),
GuardianFname VARCHAR(20),
GuardianLname VARCHAR(20),
ContactNum VARCHAR(15),
AddressLine1 VARCHAR(20),
AddressLine2 VARCHAR(20),
Teacher_ID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Pupil_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_PupilDetails FOREIGN KEY (Teacher_ID)
REFERENCES Teachers(ID)
```

Comment: Formatting is NOT done in the column. A time datatype is not stored as a string, internally it is stored as a decimal. Any formatting should be done at the application layer. But if you must do it in the database it is when the data is retrieved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cast the DateTime to Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value of `time` or `datetime` data type is not stored with format in sql server. If you want to see the time in a different format you can manipulate the way that time and datetime data types are displayed when converted to a `varchar` (or `nvarchar`,`nchar`,`char`) data type using some built in functions.

Most often with [**`convert()`** styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
select convert(char(5),convert(time(0),sysdatetime()))
```

returns: `22:01`

In sql server 2012+ you can use [**`format()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
select format(sysutcdatetime(),'HH:mm')
```

returns: `22:01`

But `format()` can be slower, take a look here: [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Bertand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: Why `varchar(5)` when you already know it's always going to be the same length? Use `char(5)` instead.

Comment: You have to escape the ':' in your pattern like this: 'hh\:mm'

Comment: @keuleJ No escape necessary, here's a demo: http://rextester.com/WSWI99897

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(CAST(getdate() AS Time),5) AS Hours
```

Answer (score -2):

SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'h:mm tt')