# how to show only time from datetime databse data in aspx page?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime

in database it is stored like this:
data type: datetime
 column Name:OpenTime
data: 01/01/00 08:00:00 AM

when I fetch the data on aspx page 
its showing like above

i want it to show only time no date in this format
08:00 AM 
what code should i add to the below code

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time

Comment: You forgot to add the code.

Comment: Did you try anything so far by yourself?

Comment: how will i add it to the <%#Eval("OpenTime")%>

Comment: i tryed to this  <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("OpenTime")) %>  but same format is showing 01/01/00 08:00:00 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try string formating in Eval

There are several ways to format the date.

```
<%#Eval("OpenTime", "{0:dd/M/yyyy}") %>
```

in your case

```
<%#Eval("OpenTime", "{0:HH:mm:ss}") %>
```

Comment: how would I compare stored time with current time to show some text   <%if (DateTime.Now > Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("CloseTime","{0:hh:mm:ss tt}"))) { %>
                                    <h3>Shop open</h3>
<% } %>

Comment: why don't you compare this in serverside and pass a string value based on condition shop open or shop close

Comment: how would i do that? i am accessing the data from sql database table how would i compare it on server side?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp check this out for datediff in sql

Answer (score 0):

You can try the query to fetch time only like this `select cast(ColumnName as time) [time]
from yourTableName`.

Comment: Depending on the database engine, that might return the correct time with the current date.  If you are going to do this in the query itself, use a function that returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime dt = new DateTime();
string dtDisplay = string.Empty;

dt=DateTime.Now;
dtDisplay = dt.ToString("hh:mm tt");

then you can display the dtDisplay value in the aspx page.