# Convert modified date and time in sql

Tags: sql-server

I want the date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format, currently when i put MODIFY_DATE as "DATE" it gives 2017-03-15 08:44:58.660 , I want to convert the date to MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: This post shows no real research or effort on your part. This is readily available on Google.

Comment: [Sql server does not store date display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

Comment: If you are using `SQL Server 2012`, you can use the `Format` function.

Comment: I think you should first understand the difference between data storage and representation and then reformulate your question to make explicit what you actually need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try with CONVERT, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) you have definition and examples...

```
CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)
```

in style you need 101...

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),<yourdatefieldHere>,101)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I'm giving the below function but throwing an error, it says 
CAST or CONVERT: invalid attributes specified for type 'datetime'   , MODIFY_DATE is the column name that gives the date and time and CTDATE is the alias.                           CONVERT(datetime(10),TEAR.MODIFY_DATE ,101) CTDATE

Comment: replace "datetime(10)" to VARCHAR(10)

Answer (score 0):

use below to convert the dates:
select getdate(),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),101)