# Date is not getting inserted into table with defined format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-datatools

I am inserting some data into a table on different SQL server , for this purpose i have created a dtsx package , 
We need data in destination table in dd-mm-yyyy format and i am using below query to convert date into desired format

```
Convert(varchar,dbo.Member.DateOfBirth,105)
```

when run query in SSMS , it gives perfectly converted data as '25-08-1989'
but when i check it in destination table after insertion, it show date as '1989-08-25' 
Can somebody tell me why destination table is not accepting date in dd-mm-yyyy format after conversion ?

I am new here , sorry for formatting mistakes ....

Comment: You don't store dates in certain formats in the database (and please, no varchar fields). You store them in a proper data type (date, datetime2 etc) and do formatting in the frontend.

Comment: @means formatting wont work when storing , have to convert when about to use it ???

Comment: Yes, the data is stored in a binary format and it doesn't contain any formatting. You need to do that elsewhere

Comment: @JamesZ ok , one thing is not clear "(and please, no varchar fields)" , why ?

Comment: [Sql server does not store date display format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028) If you are using the proper data type (date, datetime2, datetime or time) you don't need to worry about string format at all. To represent a date value as strng always use `yyyy-mm-dd` (and with time `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.nnn`) to avoid ambiguity

Comment: @ZoharPeled - `yyyymmdd` please, if no time component. On older versions, SQL Server could interpret the dashed form as `yyyy-dd-mm`. E.g. connect to a 2005 server and execute `set language british; select DATEPART(month,'2017-05-09')` and you'll get `9`, not `5`.

Comment: @Saurabh there is no such thing as a date format. They are binaries. You *don't* need any specific format in your target table. Either you have a bug in your schema and used varchar instead of `date`, or you perrforming a useless conversion. If `DateOfBirth` is a date type, just  store it directly to the target date-typed column

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I wasn't aware of that, thanks!. btw, how old?

Comment: @Saurabh post the target table's and `Member'`s schema. There's no need to convert either in SQL Server or SSIS, so you need to find where that varchar came from and fix the incorrect type

Comment: @ZoharPeled the rule is that only the unseparated format is unambiguous for dates, ISO8601 for datetimes.

Comment: @Saurabh are you confusing your *client's* display format for some server format? SSMS is nothing more than a client. In order to display the data *it* formats the date using a specific string. *Your* application or report will use a different one, typically the one that corresponds to your locale.

Comment: My comment about varchar fields was related to all the questions in SO where people have big problems with dates because someone earlier decided to store a date into a varchar, maybe because they wanted a certain format -- and that's going to be a lot of pain later when you actually need some date logic

Answer (score 0):

You are probably confusing the *client's* way of formatting dates for some (non-existent) server date format. There is none. All date types are binary values, just like int, float and decimal. The *client* formats them into strings in order to display them.

SSMS is nothing more than a specialized client. By default, dates are formatted according to *your* (the user's) locale. This can lead to confusion when the same date appears as 25/9/2017 to one user but 9/25/2017 to another. The date though is still the same.

DBAs and developers don't care about localized formats though. SSMS uses `YYYY-MM-DD` to avoid confusion.