# c# time to sql date time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2014

I am not able to convert the c# date time**7/31/2017 3:13:49 PM** to SQL date time while inserting the records to the database.

I am doing this using

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("11/23/2010");
string toSqlDate= dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime finalDate = DateTime.Parse(toSqlDate);
```

But it's giving me the error.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?

Comment: If you work with sql server, datetimes are compatible

Comment: First you're parsing a date string in a different format, then you're trying to parse the format string.  Check out the docs for [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am working with sql server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Net `DateTime` [maps directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) to SQL Server `DateTime`. This means you don't need to worry about the display format at all, since `DateTime` [does not have a display format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)
All you need to do is pass the instance of the `DateTime` struct **as a parameter** to the `SqlCommand`:

```
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateTimeParam", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt;
```

Bonus reading: [How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)

Answer (score 1):

After changing it to year/month/date this can help!

```
var sqlDate = finalDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dateformat says 'year-month-day' while your date is 'month/day/year', that can't be right. Either change your dateformat or your date's formatting.

This should work:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2010-11-23 00:00:00");
string toSqlDate= dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I understand that, but I want to insert the value 7/22/2017 3:13:49 AM into sql table.  What format would be for this.

Answer (score 1):

Change query to

```
insert into table_name (column1) values ('" + dt.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "')
```

Comment: actually I am using linq to sql.

Answer (score 1):

Try the method DateTime.ParseExact and specify The date format that is suitable for you, here is an example from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)  :

```
var dateString = "06/15/2008";
var format = "d";
try {
     var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, 
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, 
     result.ToString());
     }
  catch (FormatException) 
  {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
  }
```