# How to convert Date format (SQL Server)?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

My Table `sample` has 3 columns: `id` (`int`), `name` (`varchar`), `date_surrendered` (`date`).

I have a `DateTimePicker`; when I choose `October 8, 2018` and save it, it will save as `YYYY-dd-MM` in SQL Server. Just like this:

> id | name | date_surrendered
>
> 1 | noe | 2018-08-10

When I search about `Date` format, there's no format like `"YYYY-dd-MM"`
[Date and Time Conversions Using SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

`Form1`:

```vb
 Private Sub add_ClickS(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add.Click
    If Sql.HasConnection() = True Then
        Sql.Save(namee.Text, datesurrendered.Value)
        GridRefresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

`Conn.vb`

```vb
Public Sub Save(a, b)
     Try
         SqlCon.Open()
         SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO sample (name, date_surrendered) VALUES (
                                      @name,@datesurrendered)", SqlCon)

         SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Text).Value = a
         SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@datesurrendered", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = b

         SqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand)
         SqlDataset = New DataSet
         SqlAdapter.Fill(SqlDataset)
         SqlCon.Close()
     Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
        SqlCon.Close()
    End Try
 End Sub
```

Comment: Don't concatenate strings to buuild your sql query, parameters should **always** be passed as sql-parameter not as string. Otherwise you are vulnerable to sql injection and you have issues like this.

Comment: Okay sir, I will update you Sir.

Comment: The `Value` of a `DateTimePicker` is a `DateTime`, not a `String`.  If you create your command object properly, i.e. using parameters, then there will never be a conversion from `DateTime` to `String` so format is never a consideration.  Now that you are using parameters, your issue has gone away.  That is just one of the several reasons to ALWAYS use parameters.

Comment: By the way, if your database column is type `date` then your parameter should be type `SqlDbType.Date`, not `SqlDbType.DateTime`.  Also, you should not be using `SqlDbType.Text` unless your database column is type `text` and no database column should be that type these days.  Your database column should be type `varchar` and you should be using `SqlDbType.VarChar` and specifying the length for your parameter.

Comment: Also, the date is not saved to the database with any format.  If your column is type `date` then it is simply a number.  SQL Server displays dates in the format "yyyy-MM-dd" because it is unambiguous.  Most people would generally use "dd-MM-yyyy" or "MM-dd-yyyy" but many values in those formats are ambiguous so it is not safe to use those formats in a generic environment.

Comment: Problem solved sir :) thanks

Comment: You should also assign this command as `InsertCommand` to the DataAdapter not as SelectCommand, what you did by using the constructor that takes a `SqlCommand`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataAdapter__ctor_System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_

Comment: [Dates don't have a *display format* in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30033028/3094533) (and neither does the .Net `DateTime` struct).