# Ms sql output in date format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement. I have datetime field and I want data in datatype=date

Existing date: `2019-11-13 00: 00: 00: 000` ; datatype=datetime
Expected output require:  `11/13/2019` (mm/dd/yyyy)  ;

datatype= date

Please help me.

Comment: [DateTime have no display format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028) If you want a specific format, you need a string.

Answer (score 1):

If the core requirement is a right type then:

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() as DATE);
```

Explicit DATEFORMAT added becaise the output depends on a language settings, so can be yyyy/mm/dd or mm/dd/yyyy, some apps can be sensitive to this, as example SSRS.

However, if there is still a requirement to get value in a precisely right format **on a database side**, then consider to use a `FORMAT` statement:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: [Format() is nice and all, but...](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: If I use this, i get output datatype=nvarchar. I want data output datatype=date

Comment: The first query returns data in a right type and right format

Comment: @ZoharPeled, thanks, interesting reading, such flexibility of format comes with a price

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT()` :

```
SELECT t.datecol, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.datecol, 101) 
FROM table t;
```

Your desired date format requires `varchar` type, if you want `date` only then you can do instead :

```
SELECT t.datecol, CONVERT(DATE, t.datecol) 
FROM table t;
```

If you don't want to convert the type, then these type of conversation should do in presentation layer instead.

Comment: It is converting to varchar. I want in mm/dd/yyyy and output datatype=date

Answer (score 0):

> I have datetime field and I want data in datatype=date

If you want the data type as `DATE`, in that case you can try like following.

```
 SELECT CAST(YourDateTimeColumn AS DATE) from [YourTable]
```

Formatting part you should be doing in UI.

Comment: I'm getting in yyyy-mm-dd.  I want in mm/dd/yyyy and output datatype=date

Comment: If you want the datatype as date, in that case you need to use the default format only. Whatever formatting you want, you need to do in the UI.