# Formatting Datetime2 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, format

I am trying to format a `datetime2` into `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format.

I have tried the below options:

This is throwing an error:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, 120);
```

This works fine, but I need the output of type `datetime2`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Well, **either** you have a variable / value of type `DATETIME2` (which has **no formatting** - it's a **binary** value) - or then you convert it into a **formatted string** - you can't have both at the same time .....

Comment: _this is throwing an error: `SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, 120);`_ Sure it will because you don't specify you will convert it to what, cause you need to call `CONVERT()` as `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), DateTime2ColOrVariable, 120)`

Comment: If you want it to have a "format" and be a `datetime2`, then yo need to handle the formatting in the **presentation layer**. As @marc_s said, Date and time datatypes, in SQL Server, don't have formats, they are stored as a binary value.

Comment: [DateTime2 has no *display* format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028). Only string representations of it has a display format.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the `CONVERT()` function without specifying the data type to convert to, so in your case `SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, 120);` SQL Server will try to convert the value `120` to a `datetime2` and that's why you get this error (which you don't provide)

> Explicit conversion from data type int to datetime2 is not allowed.

To use **[`CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** with date and time styles, you need to pass

`CONVERT(<datatype to convert to>, <Value to be converted>, <Style>)`.

The **[`SYSUTCDATETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysutcdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** returns a `datetime2` you can convert to as

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SYSUTCDATETIME(), 120)
--Change SYSUTCDATETIME() with your column/variable
```

For what you say

> but I need the output of type `datetime2`

A `DATETIME` doesn't have a format, it's a binary value, thus you need to convert it to a formatted string. Since you need to return a `DATETIME2` then you need to leave it as it is, and do the formatting in presentation layer.