# How to transfer the Date Column with Format '/' to Format '-'?

Tags: sql-server

I want to transfer one Date Column with format '/' to '-', for example, one date data like '10/19/2018 2:49:47 PM', but I want the format '2018-10-19 14:49:47'. I have tried below actions, like using convert, but it seems does not work.

```
SELECT [LMDM_Data] ,convert(varchar(100),LMDM_Data,23) ,CAST(LMDM_Data as varchar(10)) FROM Table
```

Below is the result:

```
LMDM_Data   (No column name)    (No column name)
10/19/2018 2:49:47 PM   10/19/2018 2:49:47 PM   10/19/2018
```

To verify whether this column is Date, I use isDate() function to check, and they all return 1.

```
SELECT [LMDM_Data] ,ISDATE(LMDM_Data), convert(varchar(100),LMDM_Data,120) ,CAST(LMDM_Data as varchar(10)) FROM [ESS_NJ_LMDM_PDM].[dbo].[maintanence_workload]
```

Below is the result:

```
LMDM_Data   (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
10/19/2018 2:49:47 PM   1   10/19/2018 2:49:47 PM   10/19/2018
```

Comment: [Date has no display format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028) Only string representations of date has display format.

Comment: And As GSerg wrote - if you are storing dates as string, stop doing that. Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) for details.

Comment: `isDate()` returns 1 if the string it gets can be converted to date / datetime, or 0 otherwise. What's the actual data type of the column?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Bingo, it is varchar type and it can be transferred to Date.

Comment: Then you really need to fix your data type @Zoeric and then have your presentation layer worry about the format. `10/19/2018 2:49:47 PM` is not "after" `06/26/2019 8:30:32 AM` nor is "before" `10/19/2018 9:21:01 AM`; but it is according to your data.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, I have changed this column type from Varchar to Datetime and it can work normally.

Comment: Closed as duplicate, then.

Answer (score 0):

Use the style 120 (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)`)

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,LMDM_Data,120)
```

Remember this will only covert to `VARCHAR` inside `SELECT` query and not actual data in table.

See [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more format.

**UPDATE:**

In case the datatype of the field LMDM_Data is not `DateTime`, you will require to convert it to DateTime before changing the format like this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(LMDM_Data AS DATETIME),120)
```

But as everyone suggested above, storing date in VARCHAR datatype is not a good idea at all. You should fix the datatype rather than converting to datetime.

Comment: It still does not work... I have changed several kinds of arguments.

Comment: This should work. See [this example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff2b2/1).

Comment: But when I input the value '10/19/2018 2:49:47 PM', it still cannot convert to the format with '-'. Target is '2018-10-19 14:49:47'

Comment: Check the update.

Comment: Yes, when I convert the column type, it can work now!