# How to Convert 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MM.SS.MI' to 'YYYY-MM-DD' in SQL Server from DB2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, db2

From DB2, we are getting one column value "2018-01-12-13.28.37.111972" like this format("YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MM.SS.MI"). I want to convert this one to "YYYY-MM-DD" in sql server. I used Cast(fieldname as date) is not working.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in both the date and time, Larnu's answer is the way to go.
If it's only the date you care about, you can simply use `left` to get only the date part of the string:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT('2018-01-12-13.28.37.111972', 10) As Date)
```

BTW, [datetime isn't stored with a display format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for DB2, but I suspect you're it's passing the value as a `varchar`, and not a `datetime`, and hence the problem. If DB2 *has* to pass the values as a `varchar`, you have use `STUFF` to fix the values:

```
SELECT DB2.DateString,
       CONVERT(datetime2(6),STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(DB2.DateString,11,1,'T'),14,1,':'),17,1,':'))
FROM (VALUES('2018-01-12-13.28.37.111972'))DB2(DateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

With a few string functions you can transform the timestamp text to a format that can be casted to a DATE or a DATETIME

**For example this snippet:**

```
select db2col, 
try_cast(left(db2col, 10)+' '+replace(substring(db2col,12,8),'.',':')+substring(db2col,20,4) as datetime) as col_as_datetime,
cast(left(db2col, 10) as date) as col_as_date
from (values 
 ('2018-01-12-13.28.37.111972'),
 ('2018-02-15-14.29.54.123456')
) as vals(db2col)
```

**Returns:**

```
db2col                      col_as_datetime         col_as_date
--------------------------  ----------------------- ----------
2018-01-12-13.28.37.111972  2018-01-12 13:28:37.110 2018-01-12
2018-02-15-14.29.54.123456  2018-02-15 14:29:54.123 2018-02-15
```

Answer (score 0):

`select convert(varchar(10), '2018-01-12-13.28.37.111972', 5)`

will produce: `2018-01-12`

Comment: That's basically the same as select `left('2018-01-12-13.28.37.111972', 10)`. try converting this string to `datetime` and you'll get Conversion failed error.