# Can I change date format of SQL Server table permanently?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in my database.

1. Customers_Details
2. Transaction

Both tables have a `date` column. I want to change the date format from `YYYY-MM-DD` to `DD-MM-YYYY` permanently for both tables.

Can i do it in one query or do I have to write separate query for each table?

The query which I have written is not changing the format of date permanently.

```
select 
    [customer_ID], [Gender], [Area_code],
    convert(varchar, dob, 105) as DOB 
from 
    [dbo].[customer_details]
```

Comment: SQL Server's `DATE` type is a binary type that records a timestamp as a number; there is no formatting data embedded into it. It is formatted for presentation by clients. So the short answer to your question is "no", while the long one depends on what you're using to display the dates.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: [How does SQL Server store date values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028)

Answer (score 0):

`date`s are stored in an *internal* format.  You wouldn't want to look at that string of bits anyway.  But you do want to store the data that way -- to use date functions, so ordering is correct, and so on.

What you can do is add a computed column that has the string form that you want:

```
alter table [dbo].[customer_details] add dob_ddmmyyyy as (convert(varchar(10), dob, 105);
```

You can then use `dob_ddmmyyyy` in queries.

Comment: It's worth noting that it's unlikely you'll want to query that column if you're using range queries (or if you're not going to `PERSIST`) the column. `'12/05/1957'` is **after** `'09/12/2018'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method, (tested in SQL 2014 and higher)

```
select FORMAT (GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MMM-dd')
```

In your case it would be as follows:

```
 select [customer_ID],[Gender],[Area_code], 
        format(dob, 'dd-MM-yyyy') as DOB 
 from   [dbo].[customer_details]
```